# Do passenger rack processes die?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a fairly large sized rails server with many active messaging pollers talking to an ActiveMQ server.

When I start the server, it takes about 45 seconds for all the classes to be loaded in memory and the server is ready to accept requests.

Every now and then, requests to the server pause for a minute or so and at that time I see that the classes are being re-loaded in the logs.

When I monitor the rack processes, around that time, I see the old processes are gone and are replaced by new rack processes.

Do the passenger rack processes die when they are idle?  How do I make sure they don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are killed when they have been idle for a period of time. [The documentation for PassengerPoolIdleTime](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPoolIdleTime) says this is 5 minutes.

If you do not wish them to shut down set this setting to 0 in your config.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan.  Truly appreciate it.